# How to get rid of the status bar background on the UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova, uiwebview

Since iOS 11, when the `UIWebView` is full screen, a fake background appears on the status bar with the same color of the `UIWebView` background.

Anyone knows how to get rid of it?

Even adding the `IUWebView` to a storyboard and make it full screen will make the status bar background to appear

I've been trying to edit the size and some other properties of the UIWebView and none of them worked, but it's definitely something from the UIWebView.
Also tried to see all the subviews and it's sizes and didn't see anything strange.

Attached a screenshot, see the grey "statusbar", it disappears when scrolling, and doesn't appear if the `UIWebView` is not over that part of the screen.
I want it as on the second screenshot, only remove the fake background, not the status bar.

[image: See the Screenshot]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because of `UIScrollView` new behavior to adjust the content inset to include safe area insets like the status bar.

To fix it, just set it to `UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever`

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

Since iOS 11 Beta 4 you can add this to your viewport and will also remove the fake statusbar

`viewport-fit=cover`

Answer (score 3):

To do this entirely in HTML/CSS, `viewport-fit=cover` in the Viewport meta tag is the correct way to handle this.

But you'll also want to adjust your padding dynamically to handle the differently sized status bar on iPhone X with its notched camera/speaker.

Luckily, Apple exposed some CSS constants for the safe area insets, so you can take advantage of those in your CSS:
i.e., `padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);`

I wrote a bit more about this scenario and the new features for iOS 11 and iPhone X: https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: does not work. Content scrolls on the statusbar while using WebKitView