# Status bar entire view moves down - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, ios11

I recently upgraded to Xcode 9-beta and iOS 11. When I did and pushed play on my project, all of my views were pushed around 20px down by the status bar, instead of the status bar being directly on top of my view. My partner, who has iOS 10, does not have this issue. I have attached a screenshot for your reference.

Can anyone offer some advice? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers,
Theo
[image]

Comment: Check the top constraint.

Comment: did you use xcode-9 beta or beta 2 ?

Comment: @KKRocks im using xcode-9 on my computer and ios11 beta 2 on my phone. does this help?

Comment: @NikhilManapure will do, but this is happening on every single view. strange right?

Comment: i think it is xcode issue . try to check to xcode 9 beta 2.http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_2/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_9_beta_2.pdf

Comment: @KKRocks do you know for sure? dont rly want to go through the hassle of downloading if it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Not sure but if it is working in previous version of xcode so it is the xcode issue.

Comment: check it in device

Comment: @KKRocks good point

Comment: @karthik what do you mean?

Comment: try to check in previous version of xcode . or else download new xcode 9 beta 2.

Comment: @KKRocks my friend has xcode 9 beta and ios 10 but his works. i think this is a ios problem

Comment: Ok then my suggestion is right.

Comment: @KKRocks no its not bc its not an xcode problem. its an ios problem. how would ur suggestion help?

Comment: Do you have a UIScrollView? (Also happen with UIWebView or UITableView as they internally use UIScrollView) it now add safe insets, to disable it check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396880/how-to-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-background-on-the-uiwebview/45268206#45268206

Comment: Beta 4 has same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of the status bar background on the UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396880/how-to-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-background-on-the-uiwebview)

Comment: @TheoStrauss How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Ranjit it turns out it was a CarbonKit issue. Are you using that? If not, I cant' help you!

Comment: HAPPY BIRTHDAY!!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Swift answer**

You may want to set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` of your `tableView` or `scrollView` object to `.never`.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

or

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

Comment: If necessary, this can also be achieved in the storyboard. Having selected the scrollView, tableView or collectionView change the Content Insets dropdown from automatic to never.

Comment: What If I am not using tableView or scrollView

Comment: I believe this way you need to check Arthur's answer.

Answer (score 17):

I was facing the same problem and after HOURS of search, I finally found the problem.

Xcode 9 has a new concept of Safe Areas and by default, the storyboard now adds a safe area at the top of all views.

If you select the root view of your ViewController and select the Size Inspector you'll see a checkbox, as you can see on the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIJ4S.png)

Uncheck it and this top padding will go away.

Comment: it's the best answer

Comment: Slight correction, this checkbox is in the File Inspector menu.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        _tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `UITableViewStyle.grouped` - the gap of 35px will still be there even tho you add `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`.
Try changing `UITableViewStyle` to `plain`. This resoled an issue for me.

Comment: Oh my God! This is not a safe area inset - this is designed shift of section!!! You are my hero!