# UIWebView gray space top margin on ios 11 / xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

[image]

[image]

Since updating to ios 11 and xcode 9 i can't display html content from the top of the view.
seems like uiwebview is having a 20pixels inset margin

Does anyone knows how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `UIWebView` in projects after iOS 8, switch toű WKWebView` instead.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't answer my question.
Note - i tried to use also WKWebView and still having same top margin issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of the status bar background on the UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396880/how-to-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-background-on-the-uiwebview)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solves the issue

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

reference:
[How to get rid of the status bar background on the UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396880/how-to-get-rid-of-the-status-bar-background-on-the-uiwebview/45268206#45268206)

Answer (score 6):

it's only available in iOS 11+, so :

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    _webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3 and WKWebView to save someone time

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` in your VC's `viewDidLoad`

You can also set this in the storyboard

Comment: Really?  It might be on the webView itself try: `webView.scalesPageToFit = true`